# Why do some authors seem to ignore reviewer comments?

Tags: peer-review

For example a review might say:

> This paper is acceptable if the following comments are addressed:
>
> 1. In section two, change "this is a topy" into "this is a typo"
> 2. Instead of writing "Log" for the natural logarithm, write "Ln". This issue is present in sections two, three and four.
> 3. In section four, [do some serious work].

Then when the revision arrives, the authors make some attempt to address point 3 but completely do not address points 1 and 2, even though they're not controversial.

Why do some authors do this? I certainly do not want to Ctrl + F "Log" and list where all occurrences of it are when the authors can do that just as easily (besides, even if I do that, it often goes unfixed anyway). On the other hand, outright not fixing these issues when they've been pointed out seems pretty rude.

In my experience it seems that authors from India do this especially often, but I have no idea why this would be the case.

Comment: I would say: carelessness. They are confident that paper will be accepted even if point 1 and 2 are not taken care of due to being minor comments.

Comment: @AppliedAcademic does the edit help with the discriminatory aspect? If not, feel free to edit the question yourself.

Comment: @Coder hmm I'd expect some reviewers to be annoyed enough to recommend rejection because the authors aren't treating them with respect.

Comment: @Allure- Thanks, I think that's straight and unobjectionable! :)

Comment: They may not be native English speakers? I find that my grammar and spelling comments are most often ignored by people whose English was weak in the first place.

Comment: Think about how often Absorbance is given in a.u. Besides that means astronomic units I guess, there is no way to get a.u. away from a mere Absorbance. I also wonder why people don't act to correct points like those in your examples. Some are totally wrong and in an examination scenario would cause the student fails. Ps I have been thinking to be on chemistry SE :))

Comment: You ask a question with no general answer. People do things. Different people do things for different reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would do things the other way round fix 1 and 2, and not ignore 3 but maybe push back in what's asked.

Anyway back to the question, I expect it's a either an expectation that the journal will correct spelling/formatting issues (depends on the journal) or a gamble that you wouldn't reject a paper just because of a spelling mistake.

Comment: This does sound reasonable, but I wonder what would make someone take that gamble and risk rejection. Especially if the work needed is not much. I wonder if there is some perception that language/presentation is less important than the hard science itself.

Answer (score -1):

You think those points are not controversial, but they maybe are (not speaking about typos, of course). Maybe it is a bad example, but there might be some country where the natural logarithm would be written as log and the authors would like to have it that way. *[Exchange this example with anything you like.]* If that was the case, it could be discussed like that in their reply, no doubt, and it would be better, but:

I also suspect that in many such cases people do not know better. It might be good practice to reply to every reviewer comment, but not everybody follows good practice. They might be inexperienced, never got good advice on this issue, or simply do it on purpose. *[It reminds me a bit of quite a few PhD students' first attempts to prepare a reply for the reviewer comments to their first paper. They very often need good tutoring to end up with an acceptable response letter.]*

But so what? You are not the author of the paper and are not responsible for it either. You do your share with your review, and in your example it would be only fair to let the editor know of the unwillingness of the authors to improve the standard of the manuscript. Then the editor can decide.

I would not call such behavior rude, it is just wrong/not helpful. Do not take it personally.